# How could I use a non constant value to instantiate multiple objects of a class?

Tags: c++, class, constants, instantiation

For example, I'm coding a battle simulator and I want to instantiate an object for each turn (every Turn object holds a value relating to the current turn number and the Unit object the turn belongs to).

```
const int MAX_TURNS = 30;

for (int i = 1; i < MAX_TURNS; i++)
{
    Turn phase[i];
}
```

This is what's throwing up the problem. I can't use [i] when I instantiate an object, as it is not a constant value. Could somebody explain to me why this is/ any ways around this?

It may be a dumb question, but I thought something like this would save time and be easier for referencing through the objects?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want _one_ object in each turn, or `i` objects in the current turn? `Turn phase[i];` would (if `i` was a constant expression) create `i` objects, not just one.

Comment: but this just creates the objects and does nothing else. once the loop ends all the objects will call the destructor right? if you want to create the objects and let them survive beyond the loop use should allocate on the heap.

Comment: What I wanted is a pre loaded list of blank turns, so that when it comes to the battle being generated, I can use the two Units speed values to determine which turn belongs to who. Se essentially, I just want them to have numerically ending names like:

Comment: phase1, phase2, phase3, etc

Comment: @Iskardes if you want them to have  names why dont you have a member inside the `Turn` that holds their respective names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've given attempts to create `i` objects at each iteration. So in the first iteration there will be 1 object, in the second iteration there will be 2 objects. To achieve this, you must use some form of dynamic array. The best approach is to use a standard container, like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Turn> phase(i);
```

However, from your description, it sounds like you just want a new `Turn` object at each iteration. That doesn't even require an array:

```
for (int i = 1; i < MAX_TURNS; i++)
{
    Turn phase;
    // Use phase
}
```

Each iteration will begin by creating a new `Turn` object.

Now from your comments, it sounds like you want a single array of `MAX_TURNS` `Turn`s:

```
Turn phases[MAX_TURNS];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TURNS; i++)
{
    // use phases[i];
}
```

Notice that I've started `i` from `0` because arrays are indexed from 0. So the first `Turn` is `phases[0]`, the second is `phases[1]`, etc.

Comment: @Koushik Of course. I'm assuming they're going to do something else in the loop.

Comment: i'm sorry i was supposed to post it to the OP. sorry moving the comment.

Comment: So from your code that you have posted, would I be able to add a number into the name of the phase? like phase1, phase2, etc each time the loop re-iterates?

Comment: @Iskardes Look at my latest edit. I think that's what you want. You just want an array of `Turn`s of size `MAX_TURNS`. Then `phases[i]` is the appropriate `Turn` for each iteration.

Comment: "Notice that I've started `i` from `1`" - Is this a typo or am I being dumb at the moment? Because it really looks like you're (correctly) starting iteration at `i == 0`.

Comment: You're welcome! Always happy to help make a good answer better.